# How API Key mechanism in Android can secure things?

Tags: android, security

Let's take Google Maps example, to be able to show the maps we need to:

- Extract SHA1 of the public key we that corresponds to the private key we use to sign our application and save it in Developer Console (Backend)
- Get the Api Key that we save in our application resources

This results in the following:

- If another application use my Api Key, they won't get the Maps working
- If I sign my application with another key, the maps won't work as well

So following are my questions,

Why do I need to give to google the SHA1 of my public key?

How the Api key is generated? verified from the SHA1 of my public key?

How the communication is secured then?

Thanks

Comment: "Extract SHA1 of the private key" -- nope. You are getting the SHA1 of the public key.

Comment: Sorry for the error, I'll change the content of my question.